# Error Nombre de columna no existe en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta cuya finalidad es poner una etiqueta llamada `Match` para luego hacer un filtro a ese Match con un `WHERE`, pero me genera un error "Nombre de columna no existe".

Mi script es el siguiente:

```
SELECT
    [Contra], [Schedule],
    SUM(CAST([UsedSM] AS float)) AS [UsedSM], SUM(CAST([TotalSU] AS int)) AS [TotalSU],
    SUM(CAST([UsedSU] AS float)) AS [UsedSU],
    MatchExpireDate = Case When FIRST_VALUE(Schedule) OVER (PARTITION BY [Contra] 
                                                            ORDER BY [Schedule] ASC
                                                            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                                            ) = [Schedule] Then 'Match'
    Else 'Not' End

    FROM [dbMartxxx].[dbo].[tblPDPcontracts] where MatchExpireDate = 'Match'
    GROUP BY [Contra], [Schedule]
    ORDER BY [Contra]  DESC;
GO
```

Comment: Hola, Cesar, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te recomiendo le eches un ojo al [tour] y [ask] para que tengas una idea de como funciona el sitio. Actualmente a tu pregunta le faltan detalles muy importantes, tales como el esquema que utilizas y donde te arroja el error exactamente, ¿Podrías [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/167427/edit) la pregunta para agregar la información faltante? Así nos ayudas a ayudarte :D, saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente por como se procesan las consultas, en la instancia del `WHERE` no existe la columna `MatchExpireDate`, de ahí el error. Lo que puedes hacer es:

#### Usar una subconsulta

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (SELECT    [Contra],
            [Schedule],
            SUM(CAST([UsedSM] AS float)) AS [UsedSM],
            SUM(CAST([TotalSU] AS int)) AS [TotalSU],
            SUM(CAST([UsedSU] AS float)) AS [UsedSU],
            MatchExpireDate = Case When FIRST_VALUE(Schedule) OVER (PARTITION BY [Contra] 
                                                                       ORDER BY [Schedule] ASC
                                                                       ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                                                       ) = [Schedule] Then 'Match'
                                       Else 'Not' 
                     End

            FROM [dbMartxxx].[dbo].[tblPDPcontracts]
            GROUP BY [Contra],
                     [Schedule]
    ) T
    where T.MatchExpireDate = 'Match'
    ORDER BY T.Contra  DESC;
```